# How do I run unit tests using the GLib framework?

Tags: c, unit-testing, glib

I'm trying to run simple unit tests for some C code I'm writing using GLib. I'm trying to do something like:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <glib.h>

static void 
test_stuff () 
{
  g_assert (1 == 1); //Say
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  g_test_init (&argc, &argv);
  g_test_add_func ("/TestTest", test_stuff);

  return g_test_run();
}
```

But when I compile (say to a binary called exec) and try to run this using gtester (or even running said binary directly), I get the following error:

```
me@laptop:tests$ gtester exec
TEST: exec... (pid=6503)

(process:6503): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_test_init: assertion `vararg1 == NULL' failed
FAIL: exec
Terminated
```

Is there something I'm missing, maybe variables I should pass as I run the tests?

Answer (score 12):

You're missing an argument to the `g_test_init()` function. [The docs](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-Testing.html#g-test-init) show the prototype as:

```
void g_test_init(int *argc,
                 char ***argv,
                 ...);
```

and:

> ... : Reserved for future extension. Currently, you must pass NULL.

So, you need to pass a `NULL` as the third argument.

Comment: Yup, and look at your rep now :-)  If it works and you accept it, it will help others who read this question in future (just like it helped me ;-)